# docker-compose.override.yml does not override values

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to override my volume in my production environment as I don't need it there (have it on my local environment for faster development). However, adding a docker-compose.override.yml file doesn't actually "remove" my volumes (resulting in an error).

This is my **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    image: USERNAME/PROJECT_NAME
    container_name: PROJECT_NAME
    volumes:
    - ./:/usr/src/app
...
```

This is my **docker-compose.override.yml** file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    volumes: []
```

Any reason for this behaviour or alternative approaches?

Comment: How do you run it? I believe u need to use entrypoint params here,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An override in compose merges the values of the override file on top of the original file, but that doesn't unset values from the original. Merging an array with an empty array is that original array. You'll likely want to switch the logic, and have an override compose file for the environment with the volume, and the original compose file for the environment without any volumes.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would override and not merge the values. I switched the logic (let it override my compose-docker.yml file on localhost with the volume added).